# How to set a website with live information as desktop wallpaper

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, desktop-customization

Here is a [great map](http://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/surface/level/overlay=temp/winkel3) of the Earth showing live information about winds and temperature.

Is it possible to set this as a desktop background with automatic updating every few hours (the map itself updates every three hours)?

This question is similar in spirit: [How can I set the live video feed from the ISS as my desktop background?](https://superuser.com/questions/750949/how-can-i-set-the-live-video-feed-from-the-iss-as-my-desktop-background).

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu, but I'll keep the question more general.

EDIT:
The program WallpaperWebPage has the right idea, but with the following limitations:

- it covers desktop icons
- it is interactive (so when you click on the desktop it behaves like a browser)
- it only covers the desktop and can be minimised
- the map needs a modern browser and this basically runs an old version of IE in full screen mode

Comment: @ this question is closely realted! Not really, that question ask how to set a video as desktop wallpaper, your question ask how to set an interactive website as wallpaper

Comment: The questions are indeed different and so the answers to the other question are not applicable to this one.  That's why I think it justifies a new question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Rainmeter? I'm sure there is a plugin for it!

Comment: I wanted a zoomable interactive map of the world, with color mapping options! :p

Comment: You mean [Active Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop)?  Oh wait...Microsoft took that feature out of Windows.  :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active desktop for Windows 7 (Vista)?](http://superuser.com/questions/67451/active-desktop-for-windows-7-vista)

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu I use variety. It's "an automatic wallpaper changer, downloader and manager".

It can pull pictures from an RSS feed and automatically update your desktop.

Therefore, I'd imagine that if you setup an RSS feed that takes a screen shot of your website every x hours and hooked variety to it you'd have a solution.

I do not actually know how to set up a RSS feed but if you have any questions about variety let me know.

**Edit:**

Here is an other way to do what you want.

1. Run `sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyqt5 python3` to install required libraries
2. Setup a file with the following python3 code. This code takes a screen shot from WEBSITE_URL and updates your Ubuntu desktop.

   ```
   import sys
   import time
   import os
   from PyQt5.QtCore import *
   from PyQt5.QtGui import *
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
   from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *

   WEBSITE_URL='https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/surface/level/overlay=temp/winkel3'
   OUT_FILE="websiteScreenshot.png"

   class Screenshot(QWebView):
       def __init__(self):
           self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
           QWebView.__init__(self)
           self._loaded = False
           self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

       def capture(self, url, output_file):
           self.load(QUrl(url))
           self.wait_load()
           # set to webpage size
           frame = self.page().mainFrame()
           self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())

           # render image
           image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
           painter = QPainter(image)
           frame.render(painter)
           painter.end()
           print ('saving', output_file)
           image.save(output_file)

       def wait_load(self, delay=5):
           # process app events until page loaded
           while not self._loaded:
               self.app.processEvents()
           t_end = time.time() + delay
           while time.time() < t_end:
               self.app.processEvents()
           self._loaded = False

       def _loadFinished(self, result):
           self._loaded = True

   s = Screenshot()
   s.capture(WEBSITE_URL, OUT_FILE)

   #Update your background
   workingDir=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
   os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://"+workingDir+"/"+OUT_FILE)
   ```
3. In "Startup Applications" press add and type `watch -n 3600 python3 yourfilepath` under command. Replace `yourfilepath` with the path to where you saved the pythonscript. This will run the script every 3600 seconds = 1 hour.

Note the delay variable in the wait_load function. Increase it's value if the web page doesn't have time to load.

Comment: So you have a solution but you don't know how to implement that solution or even if that solution is really viable? That's not answer.

Comment: @FleetCommand I'm just trying to help... It's already a start. Sorry...

Comment: I know you are. But this isn't a "trying to help" website. This is a helping website.Your answers must be self-contained full solutions that have a very high probability of working on a healthy system.

Comment: @FleetCommand please see edit